# Not proceeding with code after while loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a simple digital clock using Tkinter. However, after I use "while True" to update the variable and the label, it doesn't create a window, even though that part is not indented. Here's my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x200')

while True
    now = datetime.now()

    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    clock = Label(root, text = current_time)
    clock.pack()


root.update()
``
```

Comment: What do you mean by "other code"?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify

Comment: The code as is doesn't even run does it?

Comment: yes, because it doesn't call the "root.update" part

Comment: When do you think that `while True` loop will end and allow the program to proceed to the next part?  As far as I can tell, it won't; you might want to do that update in another thread.  (Maybe google "tkinter clock tutorial" -- this seems like the sort of thing that would be a popular way to teach GUI programming and multithreading concepts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
...
```

Program is stucked in this part it will keep on executing it.

In order to solve the issue move `while True` logic inside a `thread`(use `Thread` from `threading` module).

Here's another simple approach we are using `clock.after(400, update)` which will call after `400` milliseconds and update the label we are using `mainloop` to ensure that main will not exit till our window is not closed.

```
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x200')

clock = Label(root)
clock.pack()

def update():
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print(current_time)
    clock.config(text=current_time)
    clock.after(400, update)



root.update()

update()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't written any python before, however I imagine that `while true` is always true, therefore you have an infinite loop where your variable `now` is being constantly updated with the new time, with no chance to break free from the loop

Answer (score 1):

Check here to see how to create a clock with tkinter.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-create-a-digital-clock-using-tkinter/

Your code will never exit the loop because while will be always looping at a very high speed because the condition is always (True).